# Why my stringfied JSON changes are not being submitted to my Controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, model, model-binding

I have a Model which I send to my View. Since this model has several complex objects in it, I use `var model = <%= Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) %>;` to expose the model to all jQuery methods as a global variable.

After I'm done editing my model (creating new items, updating existent items, and changing objects from a place to another), I post it to the controller using the following code:

```
$("#Update").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
            url: '<%= Url.Action("Update", "Editor") %>',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({aModel: model}),
            success: function (data) {
            }
        }).done(function (result) {
    });
});
```

Receiving it in my Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Update(MyModel aModel)
 {
     ModelState.Clear()
     aModel.Execute();
     return View("path/to/view");
 }
```

When I check the result of `JSON.stringify({aModel: model})`, I can see my changes. However, the object `aModel` doesn't receive this changes.

I tried to clear the ModelState, I tried avoiding caching, I tried copying an existent element from the model and changing its values, instead of creating a new item to push to a Json array, but none of these worked.

My model is like the following:

```
public class MyModel
{
     public Dictionary<string, List<Item>> Items { get; set; }
     public List<ItemProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Could the Dictionary be causing the model biding problem? Assuming it is a model biding problem.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT 1**

Based on comments, I thought the problem could be inside the complex types `Item` and `ItemProperty`. I tried to use parameterless constructors and public setters to the `Id` attribute, but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Here are the classes:

```
public class Item
{
    public const string CONST = "Value";

    private SubItem aSubItem;
    public List<SubItem> SubItems { get ; set;  }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Help { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public Item(string anId)
    {
        Id = anId;
    }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public List<ItemProperty> Properties = new List<ItemProperty>();

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public bool SubtitleVisible { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public MyEnumType Type { get; set; }

    public SubItem(string anId)
    {
        Id = anId;
    }  
}

public class ItemProperty
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public MyAction CustomAction = new MyAction();

    public ItemProperty(string anId)
    {
        Id = anId;
    }
}

public class MyAction
{
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
}
```

And the serialized model when posting. The only thing I changed from the original model is the `Name` property:

```
"{"Items":
    {"ITEM1":
        [{"SubItems":
            [{"Properties":[],
              "Subtitle":"Other",
              "SubtitleVisible":true,
              "Id":"Other",
              "Visible":true,
              "MyEnumType":0}
             ],
          "Help":"",
          "Name":"ADDED A NAME TO SEND TO THE CONTROLLER",
          "Id":"ITEM1",
          "Time":"/Date(-62135578800000)/"},
      ...
```

Comment: Can you reproduce in Dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: can you post a sample serialized object?

Comment: also the item and itemproperty classes

Comment: also a cut down controller action, showing where you put your model state clearing etc

Comment: I added some info. Your comment made me realize that the problem could be inside the complex types. I already tried parameterless constructors and public setters, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're posting a string. The fact that it *looks* like JSON is meaningless. Post the actual object. By default jQuery will encode it and send it in a format that can be parsed by your action. As you're handling it now, you're simply posting a string, which the modelbinder attempts to bind to a `MyModel` instance, but because `MyModel` is a class-type, not a string-type, it fails.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<%= Url.Action("Update", "Editor") %>',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {aModel: model},
        success: function (data) {
        }
    }).done(function (result) {
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. Since I'm using "var model = <%= Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) %>;", isn't Model (with upper-case M) the object that is binded? Shouldn't I do something like "Model = model"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you try the code modification I posted here. That should have fixed the issue.

Comment: I tried. I'm still receiving the model without the changes on my controller.